# How to apply Different Data template for each group in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, datatemplateselector

Is there anyway to apply different data template for each group in listview , I can able to do  HeaderTemplateSelector but how to do GroupTemplateSelector .

Below code i done for HeaderTemplateSelector  for group

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
    <StackPanel Margin="0.5">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplateSelector>
            <local:GroupTemplateSelector Template1="{StaticResource Template1}"
                                         Template2="{StaticResource Template2}" />
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplateSelector>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

C#

```
public class GroupTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Template1 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Template2 { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(
        object item, 
        DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            var group = item as IGrouping<string, MyClass>;
            switch (group.Key)
            {
                case "No":
                    return Template1;
                case "Yes":
                    return Template2;
            }
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

How to do different selector for Group content?

Answer (score 1):

You could just implement a `ListView.ItemTemplateSelector` and in its `SelectTemplateCore` take the `MyClass` instance and check which group does it belong to and select the template accordingly. To get the best performance, it would be best if `MyClass` had a quick way (e.g. a property) by which you could tell the group.